# Index match, need range to change based on today()

Tags: excel, indexing, range, match

I have a flow sheet that I need to read values from. Here is how sheet1 is setup:

```
equip | 11/1/2013 | 11/2/2013

car1  | travel    | return home

car2  |maintenance| 

car3  | travel    | travel
```

[image: pic jpg of sheet1 layout]

Basicly equipment in first frozen column, dates along the top row so each column under a date has the travel or maintenance for that equipment in the first column. It is a schedule for a timeline to the right.

What I need to do is find words in each row for a car but only if it is in the future.
Example: I need to find the next oil change for car1 but do not care about oil changes in the past, or in the far future beyond the first oil change in which im looking for.

Here is the index match I am using in sheet2 that works almost good enough.

```
IF(INDEX(SHEET1!3:3,MATCH("oilchange"&"*",SHEET1!5:5,0))>=TODAY(),
INDEX(SHEET1!3:3,MATCH("oil change"&"*",SHEET1!5:5,0)),"not scheduled")
```

This code has worked for any cars that do not have oil changes in the past. The cars that have an oil change in the past will return the date of the past oil change instead of the next upcoming oil change which im looking for.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Excel 2007 or later version try this formula

`=IFERROR(INDEX(SHEET1!3:3,MATCH(1,INDEX((LEFT(SHEET1!5:5,10)="oil change")*(SHEET1!3:3>=TODAY()),0),0)),"not scheduled")`

format result cell in required date format

That finds the first match when two things are true, row 5 value begins with "oil change".....and row 3 date is >= today.....and `INDEX` returns the corresponding date.

If there's no match the `MATCH` function returns an error and you get "not scheduled"

Comment: that worked perfect, the problem i was having with finding old "oil changes" results is solved.  thank you for helping me and also thank you so much for explaining your formula.  thanks again.